# Как создать bitmap большого размера в C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

Пытаюсь создать битмап 30к на 30к, но вылетает `ArgumentException`.

```cs
var bitmap = new Bitmap(30000, 30000);
```

Проблема решила библиотека ImageSharp, но с ней у меня изображения не подгружаются полностью и есть артефакты. Как создать битмап большого размера без доп. библиотек и массива битмапов (одно из решений, что я нашел на SO) ?
Если есть способ создать полотно большого размера для размещения картинок на нём, то готов рассмотреть другой способ.

Что я пробовал: прописывал gcallowverylargeobjects = true
Приложение: Консоль, .NET 6 (пробовал и .NET 5)
Компьютер мощный, ОЗУ должно хватать точно (64гб)

Comment: Битмап такого размера весит 3,6 ГБ, а зачем вам такой? Приложение 64 бит?

Comment: Покажите код создания такой картинки, который выдает исключение. НЕ угадывать же его?

Comment: var bitmap = new Bitmap(30000, 30000);

Вот здесь и вылетает исключение. Приложение 64 бит

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос, чтобы желающие ответить могли скопировать его себе и проверить, как оно работает. Так зачем вам такой битмап?

Comment: Приведите текст эксепшн и стектрейс. Ну и вообще можете глянуть код класса в месте вылета: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,280

Comment: `new Bitmap(` - из какой библиотеки этот класс?

Comment: @AK речь про .NET 5/6, а вы код от древнего фреймворка показываете)

Comment: точно. пора значит ложиться спать, а не пытаться ответы искать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Максимальный `Bitmap`, который вы можете создать с помощью GDI+ может весить максимум `int.MaxValue` байт. Это ограничение на уровне библиотеки GDI+ и обойти его невозможно, если вы конечно хотите продолжать использовать `System.Drawing`.

То есть если глубина цвета 32bpp, то размер при ширине 30000

```
2147483647 / 4 / 30000 = 17895
```

То есть код

```cs
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(30000, 17895, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

Сработает, но можно еще если вам не нужна прозрачность сделать 3 байта на пиксель 24bpp

```
2147483647 / 3 / 30000 = 23860
```

Получится так

```cs
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(30000, 23860, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

То есть, чтобы покрыть площадь 30000x30000 для полноцветного изображения, вам потребуется как минимум 2 битмапа.

Но если вам цветов надо немного, можно создать 8-битный битмар (1 байт на пиксель) и залить в него свою палитру, если требуется, тогда

```
2147483647 / 30000 = 71582
```

То есть код

```cs
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(30000, 30000, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

Сработает без проблем.

Я бы конечно посоветовал область изображения разделить на тайлы, например 10000x10000 пикселей и использовал бы 9 тайлов. Чем меньше битмап - тем быстрее с ним работать.

---

Кстати, немного арифметики

```cs
Console.WriteLine(unchecked(30000 * 30000 * 4)); // -694967296
```

То есть из-за переполнения `int` значения, GDI+ получает отрицательное число при расчете размера изображения, отсюда и возникает `ArgumentException`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный ответ